Where to deploy a python task?
I am new to Conductor and I am evaluating it for my business. I want to run a python/C# function and I can develop it using their SDK. However, I am not able to understand where these functions should be hosted for Conductor to trigger.
If I make my own task listener as shown in tutorial, then how can I do load balancing for concurrent tasks? I believe there should be a simple way to host custom code in Conductor, preferably using the Kubernetes pods.
Note: I will be installing Conductor in Kubernetes using this Helm Chart

You can deploy your Python task worker wherever you want (depending on what the task does, you have to manage the related resources needed), the worker will poll the Conductor server for tasks to execute. This is part of the distributed nature of Conductor, you can have tasks deployed at different locations and written in different languages. Polyglot and distributed.
